# permanently set display errors (PHP)

Tags: php, ini

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

This is supposed to disable display_errors, however it does not do it permanently. When I try echo ini_get('display_errors'); next time I run the script I get 1. How can I set this permanently.

Comment: To ask a possibly stupid question; are you removing `ini_set('display_errors', '0');` before you `echo ini_get('display_errors');`?

Comment: Change it in your php.ini. The runtime `ini_set` function is *not permanent*.

Comment: *After that line* it should be permanently set to `0`. Are you experiencing something different?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing php.ini settings:

```
display_errors = Off
```

or would you need it on a per-application / per-script base?

Comment: Thing to remember there might be multiple php.ini files. For apache, cli, cgi ... Depends on your server setup.

Comment: I would be ok to set in php.ini but I still get a 1.

Comment: Did you restart your Apache/IIS/... server after changing the ini direction? I would also recommend doing a phpinfo() and check the currently loaded php.ini as @E_p remarked there may be several php.ini's on your system.

Comment: I did restart and I still get a 1.

Comment: Did you also check if you were editing the right php.ini? It should be the one shown next to "Loaded configuration" on the phpinfo() page.

Comment: Another idea: I could imagine another script could have modified display_errors (i.e. some framework or library script), if phpinfo() shows display_errors = off, the setting has been changed somewhere else. You could try forbidding ini_set() through using the [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive and you'll get a warning where ini_set() has been used before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **display_errors =Off** into **php.ini** configuration file for php.

ini_set function is used to run time value for configuration parameter defined into php.ini file.

After modifying the configuration parameter in php.ini file,restart the service of apache web server and verify whether  the value of configuration parameter  display_error has been modified or not using **phpinfo()** function

For more details about **display_error** configuration parameter  please refer the documentation mentioned in below url

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Answer (score 0):

This is the extraction from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) site

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this  new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

So its not permanent. Hence change your php.ini file.